# webkit-touch-callout : none is not working iOS 8

Tags: jquery, safari, ios8, hammer.js

I have a  menu bar with a html list and links  and in some a press event with hammer.
My problem is that in safari for iOS when I press appear the popup for javascript execution.

I tried 2 things:

1. add to css the property:

   ```
   -webkit-touch-callout : none;
   ```

Not work, and in the specification of safari says that is implemented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/css/property/-webkit-touch-callout)

2. Stop de propagation of the event:

   ```
   $item.hammer().on('press', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       ...
   });
   ```

   Is not working either, maybe because safari capture the event before than me.

Comment: Did you came up with a solution? I also experience that this does not prevent hold and move on iOS Safari.

Answer (score 1):

that CSS property looks like it's missing a dash:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to put that in the message, I have that correctly in mi code and I checked with a inspector (weinre) that the property is active correctly but is not working. I read that webkit had a bug with that [here](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136685) but should be fixed and in safari should work.